# System.IO does not give methods for File in MVC contoller but System.IO.File does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, file-io, controller, .net

Why is this? I have a feeling that it has something to do with my controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NidecMotorXref.MvcUI.BaseControllers;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LINQtoCSV;
using System.IO;

     [HttpPost]
     public virtual ActionResult Matches(ImportModel model, string save, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
        { ... }
```

These are all my references but File.Delete("myfileName") does not resolve while my higher up acted like it should. Even though my solution works with System.IO.File I was curious why it doesn't resolve my reference?

Comment: Could it be ambiguous with `Controller.File`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx

Comment: Probably, just thought it was weird it would not allow both.

Comment: Both should be allowed, but if the reference is ambiguous then the compiler won't try to figure it out, it'll just complain.  You can alias one of them in the `using` directives to have a slightly different name, or more fully-qualify them when you declare them.

Answer (score 0):

Controller defines a method called `File`, therefore the compiler will choose this method when resolving the symbol `File`.

When used within a class that does not include a `File` symbol then the compiler will fall back on resolving via the using statements, hence `File.Delete` working in other classes.